# Start script are not cleared table of processes

Tags: linux, init.d, wget, init, startup-scripts

I have a proxy server, all ok. But, i have some problems & questions. 
First: when i make "/etc/init.d/nginx stop" or "/etc/init.d/nginx restart", of my config, it not reload and all nginx process are not killed.
My script:

```
case "$1" in
start)
echo Starting nginx

cd /usr/local/nginx/
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/qweqwrqwrqwraqwe/nginx.cfg?dl=0 -O nginx.cfg

/usr/local/nginx/nginx /usr/local/nginx/nginx.cfg
RETVAL=$?
 echo
 [ $RETVAL ]
 ;;
stop)
 echo Stopping nginx
 if [ /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid ]; then
 /bin/kill `cat /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid`
 else
 /usr/bin/killall nginx
 fi
RETVAL=$?
echo
 [ $RETVAL ]
 ;;
restart|reload)
 echo Reloading nginx
 if [ /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid ]; then
 /bin/kill -s USR1 `cat /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid`
 else
 /usr/bin/killall -s USR1 nginx
 fi
 ;;
 *)
 echo Usage: $0 "{start|stop|restart}"
 exit 1
 esac
 exit 0
```

When, I stop nginx, i can look, that all process are in system. Help only:

```
killall -9 nginx && servie nginx start
```

It is not good, where i have error ?

And second question. I have my configs in dropbox, when i need to reload this config, i make this (you can see this in my start script):

```
cd /usr/local/nginx/
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/qweqwrqwrqwraqwe/nginx.cfg?dl=0 -O nginx.cfg
```

Is it correctly ? May be you have correctly code ? Please help in this question.